# LibreOffice - wrong font height in formula equation / overlapping lines

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, fonts

I'm having the problem shown in the screenshots below in my LibreOffice 6.0 Writer and Math when I'm typing an equation.

As you can see in the pictures, the top of the fonts gets cut off. I've tried changing the font size, zoom and other configurations, but none of them solved the problem. And I've tested in another machine with LibreOffice 6.0 and it happens also. When I press enter it temporarily solves the problem, but if I continue typing after that, it cuts off the font again.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Follow these steps:

1. Download the new version of fonts-liberation: 
   https://packages.debian.org/pt-br/sid/fonts-liberation
2. Download the new version of fonts-liberation2: 
   https://packages.debian.org/pt-br/sid/fonts/fonts-liberation2

Install both `.deb` files and you're done. That fixed for me.