# How to change the default installed fonts-liberation-1.07.4-5 fonts-liberation2-2.00.1-5 on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: apt, 18.04, libreoffice, fonts

system: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
LibreOffice (LO), Writer: 6.0.3 default version

On Ubuntu we have installed by default those packages.
[image]

In order to fix a problem about [wrong font height in formula equation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040940/libreoffice-wrong-font-height-in-formula-equation-overlapping-lines) on LO-writer. We must update those packages to those new versions:

- fonts-liberation (1:1.07.4-7)
- fonts-liberation2 (2.00.1-7)

One user suggest us install these of Debian website [fonts-liberation (1:1.07.4-7)](https://packages.debian.org/pt-br/sid/fonts-liberation), [fonts-liberation2 (2.00.1-7)](https://packages.debian.org/pt-br/sid/fonts/fonts-liberation2). But in those links I can't find the appropriate packages, the website is very confuse to understand where these packages are, I attached these pictures to help me find the correct packages.
There are some of them? is name.orig.tar.gz or name.debian.tar.xz or some other.

[image]
[image]

After find the correct packages there, How can we install these packages?

Another user suggest us to install from Cosmic repository (Ubuntu 18.10) but , how can we do that?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fonts-liberation & https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fonts-liberation2  ; so `sudo apt install fonts-liberation fonts-liberation2`  though I gather your issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-liberation2/+bug/1769654

Comment: the answer on your linked askubuntu question looks okay to me; or using the cosmic (18.10)  version would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links to download the Cosmic versions of the packages:

- [fonts-liberation](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/all/fonts-liberation/download)
- [fonts-liberation2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/all/fonts-liberation2/download)